# Error: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an app that display videos in a recycler view , I already can storage the videos in Database Firestore , but I'm getting this error when I run my app:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.carlos.trendy.FeedRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount(FeedRecyclerAdapter.java:35)
```

My code:

```
public class FeedRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public List<Feed>feedList;

public FeedRecyclerAdapter(List<Feed> feedList){
    this.feedList = feedList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String desc_data = feedList.get(position).getDesc();
    holder.setDesc(desc_data);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedList.size();///ERROR
}

public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView desc;
    private View mView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
    }
    public void setDesc(String descText){
        desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
        desc.setText(descText);
    }
}
}
```

FeedActivity:

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context mContext = FeedActivity.this;
private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 0;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;


private RecyclerView mFeedList;
private List<Feed> feedList;
private FeedRecyclerAdapter feedRecyclerAdapter;

public void videoPicker(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(FeedActivity.this, postActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

    mFeedList = this.findViewById(R.id.feed_list);
    feedRecyclerAdapter = new FeedRecyclerAdapter(feedList);
    mFeedList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mFeedList.setAdapter(feedRecyclerAdapter);

    feedList = new ArrayList<>();


    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentChange documentChange: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                    Feed feed = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Feed.class);
                    feedList.add(feed);
                    feedRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });



    setupBottomNavigationView();


}

private void setupBottomNavigationView() {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, bottomNavigationView);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


}

public static class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView = mView;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc){
        TextView post_desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }
}

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: post the code from your activity that sets the adapter

Comment: I already edit the post

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialize the adapter here:  
`feedRecyclerAdapter = new FeedRecyclerAdapter(feedList);`  
but `feedList` is null.  
You must initialize it   
Move all these lines:

```
feedRecyclerAdapter = new FeedRecyclerAdapter(feedList);
mFeedList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mFeedList.setAdapter(feedRecyclerAdapter);
```

after this line:

```
feedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks  , that worked. Very thankful :)

Comment: I'm glad_______